# What is the hyphen used for in shell script argument parsing?

Tags: shell, parameters

I don't know why we use a hyphen for parameters of Shell. As I know, $1, $2 ... are the first, second parameter.

So my question is:
When do/don't we need a hyphen for a parameter?

For me, when I write my own shell scripts, I always pass parameters without a hyphen. For example, `myShell.sh param1 param2 param3`.

However, for other shell scripts, we use hyphens. For example `ls -l myDir`. If I'm right, there are two parameters for `ls`: `-l` and `myDir`. Why do we use a hyphen for `l` but not for `myDir`?

Comment: See: [Arguments, options and dashes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128778/arguments-options-and-dashes/128810#128810).

Comment: Re: `when I write some of my own shells` -- did you mean *shell scripts*?

Comment: BTW, the "dash" StackOverflow tag is for questions about a specific shell named dash, not for the dash character.

Comment: Also, this doesn't actually have anything at all to do with shells. `ls -l` is a UNIX command, not a shell command -- you can run it from a program written in Java or C or Python or whatever with no shell involved at all.

Comment: BTW, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html is the standards document which describes POSIX conventions for command-line parsing.

Comment: what is the difference between Unix command and shell command?

Comment: Any shell command that *isn't* also a UNIX command is something that's built in and only available from the shell. For instance, while there may exist a `/usr/bin/cd`, only the shell builtin named `cd` can actually change the directory in a shell invocation that calls it, as any external command necessarily runs as a subprocess.

Comment: ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/idx/sbi.html for a list of special builtins (thus, things that are exclusively shell commands in POSIX sh). Extended shells may add extra builtins; for instance, ksh and derivatives have `declare`. Similarly, shell functions are exclusive to the shell in which they're defined, rather than being accessible to other software.

Comment: (See also the "Command Search and Execution" section of the POSIX sh spec under http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01, listing commands that are required to be available but aren't special built-ins; these are typically... well, regular, non-special builtins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyphen (`-`) is used to differentiate the options with other arguments.

I am using your example `ls -l myDir` to explain. How will you differentiate whether `l` is option to output long lists or you want to list a file named `l`?